# How do I become an honorary member in the white glove society?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am trying to complete the quest beyond the beef but I can't seem to get Marjorie to allow me to become a honorary member no matter what i do, can someone tell me what might need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your reputation on the Strip must be "accpeted" or higher. Then Marjorie will sponsor you as a member and give you formal wear and a key to the Members-Only section.

Comment: What is a good way of getting my reputation up on the strip?

Comment: @MediocreMemer1 that would be a separate question